# Excel macro code for clearing formulas in cells does not work when the sheet is protected

Tags: excel, vba

After some googling I finally found some code where I could prevent users from placing formulas inside cells. It works great, that's until I protected the sheet. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I'm really new to VB.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.EnableEvents = False
On Error Resume Next
Range("I39").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas).ClearContents
On Error GoTo 0
Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
End Sub
```

The entire code for my sub is as follows. I need to stop users from pasting in the cells and putting formulas in them.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C26")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.CutCopyMode = True
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        On Error Resume Next
        Range("C26").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas).ClearContents
        On Error GoTo 0
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm a little confused by your question. If you're protecting the sheet, there should be no need to clear cells your users are putting formulas in, because they can't put them in in the first place because the sheet is protected. Right? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: ahh... Nope, your right. What I'm doing is an accounting form where users need to incode certain values at certain cells. Some cells needs to be protected such as account names, descriptions and formula cells while the unprotected cells are for data input.

Comment: do you means to protect certain cells only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a version that facilitates formula checking over a range of cells:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rNoFormulas As Range
    Set rNoFormulas = Range("C26:I26")
    If Intersect(Target, rNoFormulas) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If Target.HasFormula Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Target.ClearContents
        MsgBox "formulas not allowed in cell " & Target.Address
        Target.Select
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to allow data entry in cell C26, but not formula entry, then use the Change Event:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rNoFormulas As Range
    Set rNoFormulas = Range("C26")
    If Intersect(Target, rNoFormulas) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If rNoFormulas.HasFormula Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        rNoFormulas.ClearContents
        MsgBox "formulas not allowed in cell C26"
        rNoFormulas.Select
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks! It works. My only question now is how do I make it work for multiple cells. such as Range("C26:I26"). I tried doing this but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to protect certain cells only, no vba code is need. 
follow this step :
Open sheet that contains cells or columns that you want to protect, press ctrl while selecting those cells or column to be protect, then right click, choose format cells, choose protection tab and uncheck the locked option. those cells or column will not be locked although you have protected the sheet. default setting is all cells in the sheets is locked so you must choose which cells you want to unlock while protecting the sheet. you may record a macro if you still want to use vba. hope this help

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the feedback, but the problem is not only about protecting the sheet. It's about my vba code above not working when the sheet is protected.

Comment: so before protecting the sheet you are able to run your macro? then why not unprotect your sheet before the event procedure start and protect it again after the event procedure finished.

Comment: I can't unprotect the sheet because the user might do something out of context such as accidentaly change the discriptions or alter the computation formulas. We always assume that our users have the mental capacity of a 4 year old and wants to make our lives a living hell. These macro's are for validation purposes and not for calculating procedures.  =D